# How to build a Serializer for a Normalized DataBase

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Maybe my question has already been answered, but I could not find anything.
Lets say that Im building a stock inventory system using Django + Django REST for the backend. To supply this I have this two models:

```
class Shoe(models.Model):
   _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   description = models.CharField(null=False, blank = False)
   provider = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False)
   category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORIES, null=False, blank=False)

class Sizes(models.Model):
   shoe_id = models.ForeignKey(Shoe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   size = models.IntegerField(choices=SIZE_LIST, null=False, blank=False)
   amount = models.IntegerField(null=False,default=0)
```

My doubt is, how can I (using ModelViewSet, cause based on my experience with DRF is the easiest way) serve JSON files like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "description": "Air Max Black",
        "provider": "NIKE",
        "category": "Casual",
        "available_sizes": {36: 400, 37: 250}, #size: amount
        "amount": "650"                        #total amount
    },
]
```

Based on what I understand of DRF to "join" the two models in a JSON I should write a custom serializer right?
Usually my serializers are like

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ['some_stuff_here']
```

Please help me or recomend me reading material for do that, I have read the DRF docs about Serializers but  cant understand how to do stuff like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a [nested relation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships):

```
class ShoeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Shoe
        fields = '__all__' # all for all fields, or a tuple with the fields


class SizeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    shoe = ShoeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Size
        fields = '__all__'
```

But I believe your model is inverted, maybe `size` should be a fk on `shoe` model if you want to bring the size of an shoe instance? If that is the case, just invert the serializers.

Comment: One shoe has a lot of sizes availeble, so each size entity has a shoe_id as fk and a number size realted right ? Ill read about nested relations thank you.

Comment: So, if a shoe can have a lot of sizes (makes sense), you will need a `ManyToMany` field. Otherwise, you will need to create the same shoe size to every Shoe object. Drop the shoe fk on the size model, and add a field `available_sizes = models.ManyToManyField(Size)` on your shoe model. This way, you can just add new sizes calling my_show_instance.available_sizes.add(new_size)`

Comment: For an especific Shoe in addition to have a lot of sizes in stock, each size has an amount available. I think the way that I structure my Models are correct. There is no need to use a mtm, ill have a lot of "7.5" in size table, but each one for its respective shoe with the correct amount in stock.

Comment: Oh, in that case, I think you should use a new model to aggreate shoe model and size, with a field for the amount. Just to keep you in the S on SOLID.

Comment: Do you think that I need 3 models to implement this ? If I implement like you suggest the size table will have a maximus of 10 entries (like 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8). Why would I create a Model just for this ? In my way my db is 3NF, cant understand why 3 models should be better.

Comment: Don't worry too much about having a lot of models. It is bad to have unnecessary models. But is also bad having a bad model design just to save one model. I am not saying your approach is bad, but from a modeling perspective, I would have a model to track inventory, a model for the shoe itself, and one for sizes and other attributes of the shoe.